# read access violation when assigning to std::function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass a callback to a member in one of my classes. The member is held in a shared_ptr because class A is not the only owner.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class B {
public:
    void update() {
        cb(5);
    }
    void set_callback(std::function<void(int)> callback) {
        cb = callback; // exception thrown here
    }
private:
    std::function<void(int)> cb;
};

class A {
public:
    A() : b() {
        b->set_callback([](int x) {
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
        });
    }
    void update() {
        b->update();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<B> b; // seemingly the culprit
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.update();
}
```

This program should print `5`, but I get an read access violation from inside the "functional" STL header. [Here are screenshots of the exception and call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePE8u.jpg). In the code, changing `std::shared_ptr<B>` to `B` fixes the read access violation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` doesn't point to anything. `A() : b() {...}` just initializes the `shared_ptr` instance. You have to allocate a `B` with `make_shared`:

```
A() : b(std::make_shared<B>()) { ... }
```

But from this code we can see there's really no reason to use a pointer. A `B` instance on the stack would do just fine.

Comment: You're right. I didn't include the full problem in the code, I tried to stick to a minimal reproducible example. But in the actual application, I need it to be behind a ```shared_ptr```. Thank you!